# Why the function called by setTimeout has no callstack limit?

Tags: javascript, browser, settimeout

```
timer =  window.setTimeout(function () {
    //do something
    window.setTimeout(arguments.callee, 1000);
}, 1000);
```

the result is that these codes work well.

but why **doesn't it** cause the error below?

> Maximum Call Stack Size Exceeded

when debugging it, find the variable scope don't include the scope of previous executed "setTimeout function"

Who can explain this?

with documentation preferably.

Comment: This is a recursive call though, it's self referential. While we're here - OP don't use `arguments.callee` if you want a function expression and you want to call it recursively - name it: `setTimeout(function foo(){ setTimeout(foo,1000);})`

Comment: yes,the arguments.callee is dumped in the future.but in on screen, the new Function () {} ,you must use arguments.callee to get the function

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`setTimeout` is asynchronous (it returns before executing the callback), and the callback will be executed on a new, empty stack frame. That's the whole purpose. It will never overflow the stack.

It is not a recursive call, for which scope (in case of a non-[tail-call](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_call)-optimized function) would need to be retained. But that would also mean that the function became blocking, which is not what you want.

Comment: Oh, he is asking why it _doesn't_ cause a StackOverflow. I totally missed that. You might want to mention that you _can_ get the stack trace in newer versions of chrome that have async stack traces.

Comment: are there documents to explain  what you say?

Comment: @SKing7 there is the DOM timers API that specifies how it should work, and I can send you a link to the implementation in chrome - but that's not too helpful. http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/timers.html here is the timers API.

Comment: @SKing7: I just found https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/EventLoop. If you're looking for something official, the HTML5 timer spec might be able to explain this as well, but in very complicated terms only.

Answer (score 3):

This is because the Timeout callbacks are not stored in the stack as you are assuming: there are in a queue, waiting to be executed in its own stack. And in your code the queue is filled when the previous execution is completed, so the queue is not growing.

UPDATE: You can check the specs [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/timers.html), but I'm copying the text:

> The setTimeout() method must run the following steps:
>
> 1. Let handle be a user-agent-defined integer that is greater than zero
>      that will identify the timeout to be set by this call.
> 2. Add an entry to the list of active timeouts for handle.
> 3. Get the timed task handle in the list of active timeouts, and let
>      task be the result.
> 4. Get the timeout, and let timeout be the result.
> 5. If the currently running task is a task that was created by the
>      setTimeout() method, and timeout is less than 4, then increase
>      timeout to 4.
> 6. Return handle, and then continue running this algorithm
>      asynchronously.
> 7. If the method context is a Window object, wait until the Document
>      associated with the method context has been fully active for a
>      further timeout milliseconds (not necessarily consecutively).
> 8. Otherwise, if the method context is a WorkerUtils object, wait until
>      timeout milliseconds have passed with the worker not suspended (not
>      necessarily consecutively).
> 9. Otherwise, act as described in the specification that defines that
>      the WindowTimers interface is implemented by some other object.
> 10. Wait until any invocations of this algorithm started before this one
>       whose timeout is equal to or less than this one's have completed.
>
>     Optionally, wait a further user-agent defined length of time.

Comment: are there documents to explain what you say?