# How to perform 2 javascript functions interleaved?

Tags: javascript, function

I have two functions and need to execute one function every 30 seconds.

Example, execute `title()` and after 30 seconds execute `subtitle()`, after 30 seconds, `title()`.

I need to use `setInterval()` to execute the functions.

Comment: This can be done easily using setTimeout. Any reason why you want to use setInterval?

Answer (score 2):

```js
function a() { document.write('a ') }
function b() { document.write('b ') }
function c() { document.write('c ') }

fns = [a, b, c]

inter = setInterval(function() {
  
  fns[0]();
  fns.push(fns.shift());
  
}, 1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

**UPD** just figured out, that you have to use setInterval. Therefore, georg's answer is the best at the moment.

---

I came up with this quick solution.

```
var functions = [title, subtitle];

(function loop(i) {
    functions[i]();
    setTimeout(loop, 30e3, Number(!i));
})(0);
```

There is a tuple of 2 functions (title and subtitle) and a loop function, which immediate calls a first function and then initiates a timer for 30 seconds to call self again with the index of the second function.

Currently, this is an infinite recursion. <s>The only restriction is a callstack size.</s>

Comment: No, [it's not restricted by stack size](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24631041/1048572).

Comment: Oh! Thank you @Bergi

Answer (score 0):

With setInterval You can do this using a simple flag.

```
var flag = true;

function title() {
  console.log('title');
}

function subtitle() {
  console.log('subtitle');
}

function wrapper() {
  if(flag) {
    title();
  } else {
    subtitle();
  }
  flag = !flag;
}

setInterval(wrapper, 30000);
```

Comment: @user1505698 can you vote and mark this as answer if you are satisfied with this. thanks