# Call asynchronous function recursively

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, recursion, stack-overflow

I have an asynchronous function that I want to call multiple times in a row.
The problem is that "multiple" can be a few hundred thousand or millions...

The obvious way is to call the same function from the callback like that:

```
function foo()
{
    asyncBar(foo);
}
```

Of course some logic is involved to stop the recursion. The question is whether the stack is filling with calls and may cause stackoverflow at some point?

Comment: [No](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24631041/1048572).

Comment: Why don't you just run the program and view the stack in devtools?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> The question is whether the stack is filling with calls and may cause
>   stackoverflow at some point?

**No.**  If `asyncBar()` calls the callback it is passed asynchronously, then there is no stack build-up.

In your code:

```
function foo() {
    asyncBar(foo);
}
```

here is what is happening, step-by-step:

1. First `foo()` is called.
2. This then calls `asyncBar(foo)`.
3. Because `asyncBar` is asynchronous, that means it starts an asynchronous operation (let's suppose it is an http GET, but any async operation will do).  That asynchronous operation is initiated, but then `asyncBar()` immediately returns.
4. That initial call to `foo()` returns and the stack is completely unwound.  There is no `foo()` on the stack any more.
5. Any code after the call to `foo()` continues to run until it is done and returns back to the event loop.
6. Meanwhile the asynchronous operation finishes some time in the future.  That places a call to your callback in the event queue.
7. When the JS engine is done executing other Javascript (which means the stack is completely empty), it pulls that event out of the event queue and calls the callback.
8. In this case, the callback function is `foo` so it calls that function and starts the cycle all over again, right back to step 2.

There is no stack build-up.  The key is that asynchronous callbacks are called sometime later, after the current stack has finished, unwound and returned back to the system.

Answer (score 1):

> The question is whether the stack is filling with calls and may cause
>   stackoverflow at some point?

If the method is asynchronous, then you won't get **stackoverflow** at all.

check this example below

```
function f1(n)
{
   if (n > 0 ) 
   {
       callAsynch(n, function(n){
          f1(n-1)
       });
   }
}
```

This `callAsynch` could be an Ajax call (or anything that is asynchronous) which takes a callback method as a parameter.

It is not pilling on the stack since each call ends with a call to an asynch method which is not returning the value back to this method, rather simply appending a task (calling `f1(n-1)`) to the queue after it is done.

Answer (score 0):

No stackoverflow in case of async calls.
Also,
You can use **async** module's **during** method [link](https://github.com/caolan/async#during), for recursively calling a async function.