# Non-recursive pagination with promises

Tags: javascript, recursion, pagination

With a typical pagination API that returns

```
{
    "data": ...,
    "nextPageHref": <url>
}
```

how can I fetch all the pages in JavaScript **without using recursion**?

(the recursive solution is something like)

```
fetchPaginated(url) {
  return fetch(url).then(result => result.nextPageHref
    ? fetchPaginated(result.nextPageHref).then(results => _.concat(result, results))
    : result
}
```

Comment: Why do you want to do it without recursion?

Comment: nicer stack traces and JS isn't tail-recursive (at least not everywhere, not for a while)

Comment: If your using a thenable, I believe a proper Promise spec library, should be doing something similar too nextTick, so your stack should clear down.  If that's what you mean by a `nicer stack traces`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK the only way to do it without recursion is a native support to async-await and use a for loop. Note that compiled async-await will compile to some disguised recursive code too.

But this recursion is not recursion, as the call to `fetchPaginated` is called from a callback, so the sync call stack will always be emptied before the callback (And thus it is little to do with tail recursion). If you are concerned about the browsers async call stack (which is there for debugging purposes only, we don't need async call stack to run a program), I think there should be a checkbox somewhere in the browsers developer tools to turn it off.

[image]

Comment: that's a really good point the calling function will be done before the recursive call happens. thank you!

Comment: really good step-by-step explanation [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37406665/3099140)

Answer (score 0):

I guess you could send the total number of pages upon asking for the page - `/get_page?page_num=4`:

```
{
    "data": ...,
    "number_of_pages": 73
}
```

this will let you know if you can ask for page 5.

Additionally it has an advantage that you can let user skip 5 pages or access the last page, which you can't do with the approach you suggested.

Comment: My API only supports token based pagination. I have to fetch page `n` to be able to fetch page `n + 1` (note that many real life APIs such as google's and facebook's follow this pattern to enforce that people actually use pagination rather than bypass it by requesting every page simultaneously)

Comment: @JonathanR Then why do You want to bypass pagination?

Comment: you could assign the current page to the token and then just use `/get_next_page` to get the next page and `/get_first_page` to reset the counter.