# How to make an synchronous POST request in a for loop?

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, asynchronous, puppeteer

I have an array of URLs that I am sending to the backend to retrieve screenshots via Puppeteer. On the front end, I am sending the URLs by looping thru the array and sending the request. Since the POST request is asynchronous, I am getting the images out of order. How can I make it so that the images come back in the order of the array?

Here is my frontend code:

```
for (i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    var count = 0
    $.post("/api/screenshot", { url: array[i] })
      .done(res => {
        const { result } = res
        count++
        console.log(count)
        console.log(res)
        var img = document.createElement("img");
        img.src = "data:image/png;base64," + result;
        img.height = "500";
        var preview = document.getElementById("test");
        preview.appendChild(img);
        if (count == array.length) {
          $("#load-btn").hide()
          $("#ss-btn").show()
        }
      })
  }
```

My backend code:

```
app.post('/api/screenshot', async (req, res) => {
  const { url } = req.body

  try {
    let screenshot = await takeScreenshot(url)
    let img = screenshot.toString('base64')
    res.send({ result: img })
  } catch (e) {
    // catch errors and send error status
    console.log(e);
    res.sendStatus(500);
  }
});

async function takeScreenshot(url) {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
    headless: true,
    args: ['--no-sandbox']
  });
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.goto(url, { waitUntil: 'networkidle0' });
  await page.setViewport({
    width: 1400,
    height: 1000,
    deviceScaleFactor: 1,
  });
  const screenshot = await page.screenshot()

  await browser.close();
  return screenshot;
}
```

Comment: You can try putting an `await` before `$.post`

Comment: Or map array of the $.post promises and use Promise.all() whose results will be in same order as urls

Comment: Use { async: true, url: array[i] } or use [recursive async function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37405115/8153505)

Comment: @NamNguyen `async:true` is the default and `async:false` should never ever be used and is deprecated by browser vendors

Answer (score 0):

This might help:

```
let yourUrlArray=["url 1", "url 2","etc"]
await yourUrlArray.reduce(async(promise,url)=> 
   {
        await promise;
    // do your stuff with url
       $.post(url)
    },Promise.resolve())
```

This way reduce will await until $.post finish to run to solve the promise per each element in array

Comment: I can't imagine this does what you think it does.

Comment: You need to return the promise inside the reduce function

Answer (score 0):

Here's an idea:

```
var images = ['image1', 'images2']

function doNext(){
  var url = images.shift()
  if(url){
    $.post("/api/screenshot", { url })
      .done(res => {
        // do stuff here
        // keep calling doNext until images is empty
        doNext()
      })    
  }
}

doNext()
```

This avoids some of the es6 compatibility issues that some browsers still have