# Node forever loop with async calls run out of stack space

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

I have some Java

```java
while(true) {
  String result = http.get(url);
  process(result);
}
```

Which I want to turn into JavaScript to run on Node.  But both the get and process functions are asynchronous, and have callbacks.

```js
function loop(process){
  http.get(url, function(result){
    process(result, function(){
      loop(process);
    });
  });
};
loop(process);
```

I think this will work.  I don't want the code to make the next HTTP call until processing results finishes, but I think this will make me run out of stack space quickly.  How can this code be improved so that it will run forever without eating up more memory?

**Edit:** I was incorrect.  This will not eat up the stack.  The outer calls are resolved and taken off the stack before the callbacks are triggered.

Comment: *"but this will make me run out of stack space quickly"* how sure are you about that?

Comment: Have a look at [why the funcion called by setTimeout has no callstack limit?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24631041/1048572)

Comment: I was incorrect on this point