# How do I deal with recursive callback in node?

Tags: javascript, node.js, recursion, callback

I am using the [Robinhood-node](https://github.com/aurbano/robinhood-node) API to retrieve my security portfolios. The API has two functions that I use -

```
orders(callbackfn)
```

Retrieves the last 100 orders and a link to the next page.

```
url(url,callback)
```

To fetch the next page with 100 more orders.

Both these functions return a JSON that looks like -

```
{
    results:[
        {order 0},
        {order -1},
        ...
        {order -100}],
    next: url_for_next_page
}
```

Now, I need to pass the next url to the `url` function to get another 100 orders. The last page has `next: null`.

The `url` cannot be called till I process the results of `orders`. The subsequent urls cannot be called till the previous `url` results are processed. This has caused me create a callback hell :-( order -> url -> url -> url ...

I cannot call the `url`method in a loop. The loop continues to execute before the callback executes.

How do I call `url` repeatedly? I have so far managed a hack using recursive function calls. Here is my code - https://gist.github.com/lordloh/f5c8c589b4538ab9674db919ae2e2834

I am learning node js as I go... :-/

Comment: Yes, a recursive approach is the only way to solve asynchronous traversal.

Comment: Should I not be concerned about running out of stack space? Especially since I do not know how many recursions I possibly have to make. And as time passes, I shall have more transactions and the number of recursions shall increase.

Comment: @LordLoh., it's a very good point. I updated my answer to avoid this problem - if you add a `setTimeout` with `0` time, the function will be added to the event queue and there will be no chance to run out of stack space.

Comment: @LordLoh. [No](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24631108/1048572). Your function is asynchronous, the callback will be called with a new stack.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered using [`Promises`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) to avoid the callback hell?

I took a look at your code and I imagine something like this using `Promises`:

```
const credentials = {
    username: 'username',
    password: 'Password'
};

const Robinhood = require('../robinhood-node/src/robinhood');

function orderHandler(orderArray,allOs){
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => 
    {       
        for (let i = 0; i < orderArray.length; i++) {
            var e = orderArray[i];
            var ss = e.instrument.split('/');
            var instrument = ss[ss.length-2];
            allOs.push({'id':e.id,
              'instrument':instrument,
              'quantity':e.quantity,
              'price':e.average_price,
              'side':e.side,
              'transaction_time':e.last_transaction_at
            });
        }
        resolve(allOs);     
    });
}

Robinhood(credentials, () => 
{
  Robinhood.orders(function(e,r,b){   
    orderHandler(b.results,[]).then((allOs) => 
    {
        urlSequence(b.next, allOs).then((allOS) => csv(allOs));             
    });
  });       
});

function urlSequence(url,allOs){
    if(!url)
        return Promise.resolve(allOS);

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) =>
    {
        Robinhood.url(url, (e,r,b) => 
        {
            orderHandler(b.results, allOS)
                .then((allOs) => {
                    setTimeout(() => resolve(urlSequence(b.next, allOs)), 0);                       
                });     
        });     
    });
}

function csv(Arr){
    var A;
    for (var i=0;i<Arr.length;i++){
        A=Arr[i];
        console.log(A.id+", "+A.instrument+", "+A.quantity+", "+A.price+", "+A.quantity+", "+A.side+", "+A.transaction_time);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well let's say we have a function called `fetch` and all it does is to fetch some data and pass it to a callback, this is how it would be done:

```
function getAllPages(url, callback) {
  // This is a function that returns a function:
  const getPage = (oldData) => (response) => {
    // We concat the data from the response to our collected list:
    const newData = oldData.concat(response.results)

    if(response.next && response.next.length) {
      // Call the function returned by getPage passing in newData
      // This is what we call recursion
      fetch(response.next, getPage(newData))
    } else {
      // If there is no next page we just pass all the collected data to a callback:
      callback(newData)
    }
  }

  // We pass it an empty list as initial data:
  getPage([])({next: url, results: []})
}

getAllPages('some url...', (data) => {
  console.log(data)
})
```

I hope this will help you to get going.

If there are too many pages, you could easily add some throttling using `setTimeout` or set a limit.