# about retry pattern and recursion in javascript with promise

Tags: javascript, recursion, promise

I'm trying to write a simple retry-promise-pattern, to solve a generic retry problem in ajax request... now I've found this source code which works well

```
 function keepTrying(otherArgs, promise) {
    promise = promise||new Promise();

    // try doing the important thing

    if(success) {
        promise.resolve(result);
    } else {
        setTimeout(function() {
            keepTrying(otherArgs, promise);
        }, retryInterval);
    }
}
```

similar to this, there're more example at this link  https://gist.github.com/briancavalier/842626

but my question is: 
if I call keepTrying(otherArgs, promise); can I consider it just recursion?
with overload stack problem? if yes, there's something pattern o trick to avoid recursion?

Comment: Your usage of promises absolutely does not work. But no, the [pseudo-recursive call within the `setTimeout` callback does not lead to stack overflows](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24631108/1048572).

Comment: ok, the problem afaik is to call keepTrying inside itself, or not, if there's no setTimeout at all is a kinda recursion?

Comment: If it wasn't asynchronous, it would be plain recursion, yes.

Comment: `promise = promise||new Promise();` - not a regular Promise then I take it

Comment: Even if it added to the stack, it'd have to retry (potentially) thousands of times before overflowing