# Leaving recursive functions running forever?

Tags: javascript, function, loops, paradigms

I came across a function where it had a `setTimeout` inside with a timeout growing exponentially `(timeout *= 2)`.

```
let timeout = 10000
function foo() {
    // doSomething without breaking, returning
    setTimeout(foo, timeout)
    timeout *= 2;
}
foo()
```

It seems that this should not be a problem and intuitively feels like `setInterval` is kinda doing the same already *(having an infinite loop until it's cancelled if ever)*, however, my question is in the approach itself.

- Is this something that could lead to memory leaks?
- Is it better/clearer to still limit the number of calls to the function?
- Would other languages use such approach or are there different mindsets outside of JS world?

Comment: @RobIII Thanks for the comment. No, it doesn't break there.

Comment: As others pointed out, I was wrong about the `stackoverflow`; my bad.

Comment: See also [Why the function called by setTimeout has no callstack limit?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24631041/1048572), [Why such recursion not getting stack-overflowed?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56937740/1048572) and [Why does a function with setTimeout not lead to a stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61986701/1048572)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is not a recursive function call. The call to `setTimeout` will cause `foo` to be called by the JavaScript event loop at a later time.

This code will not cause a stack overflow or any such problems. It should be completely safe.

To understand how this works in-depth, I suggest reading up on the JS event loop and microtasks.

Answer (score 0):

Is this something that could lead to memory leaks?

-If the function FOO() runs to completion before the timeout calls it again then no.  The stack should be cleared.

Is it better/clearer to still limit the number of calls to the function?

-Yes, since your timeout variable will eventually overflow and may cause unintended results.

Would other languages use such approach or are there different mindsets outside of JS world?

-Depends on how the timer functions works for the library/language you use.  But this seems like a simple way and valid way to have an increasing timeout.