# Adding class to group of span tags one by one

Tags: javascript, html, css

I got html structure like this:

```
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <span class="block done" id="1"></span>
        <span class="block" id="2"></span>
        <span class="block" id="3"></span>
        <span class="block" id="4"></span>
        <span class="block" id="5"></span>
    </div>
    <script src="loaders.js"></script>
</body>
```

My current goal is to add every 1s class "done" (its some kind of simple loading bar) to spans one by one and when last span got "done" class everything restart and loop over and over. Can someone help me how to write this in vanilla JavaScript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it like this:

```js
var blocks = document.getElementsByClassName('block');

(function animateProgress(n) {
  for (var i = 0; i < blocks.length; i++) {
    blocks[i].classList[i < n ? 'add' : 'remove']('done');
  }
  setTimeout(function() {
    animateProgress((n + 1) % (blocks.length + 1));
  }, 400);
})(0);
```

```css
.block {
  float: left;
  background: #eceded;
  padding: 1em;
  margin: 1px;
}
.block.done {
  background: #7be47b;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <span class="block"></span>
  <span class="block"></span>
  <span class="block"></span>
  <span class="block"></span>
  <span class="block"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! i love this solution :)

Comment: Is it me or the call stack is gonna become humongous ?

Comment: @ZohirSalak It's you :) [Why the function called by setTimeout has no callstack limit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24631041/why-the-function-called-by-settimeout-has-no-callstack-limit)

Comment: Oh my, That's a handy thing to know, i had absolutely no idea. Thanks :)